# How to include empty COUNT result

Tags: mysql

I'm struggling with a MySQL query.

The query I wrote is skipping empty `lists`.

[Table data Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R9A2O.png)

My attempts:

```
#### 1 ####
SELECT lists.id, name, COUNT(items_x_lists.listId) AS count, SUM(items_x_lists.purchased) AS purchased
FROM lists
INNER JOIN items_x_lists ON lists.id=items_x_lists.listId
GROUP BY lists.id;

#### 2 ####
SELECT listId AS id,lists.name, COUNT(listId) AS count, SUM(purchased) AS purchased
FROM items_x_lists
INNER JOIN lists ON listId=lists.id
GROUP BY listId;
```

My attempt result (*both queries same result*):

```
id|name       |count|purchased
--+-----------+-----+---------
2 |Elgiganten |3    |0
1 |ICA        |1    |1
```

My goal:

```
id|name       |count|purchased
--+-----------+-----+---------
2 |Elgiganten |3    |0
1 |ICA        |1    |1
3 |asd        |0    |0
4 |Test       |0    |0
5 |Tester     |0    |0
```

Here are the table setup queries:

```
CREATE TABLE items (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE lists (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE items_x_lists (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  purchased TINYINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  itemId INT,
  listId INT,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (listId) REFERENCES lists(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (itemId) REFERENCES items(id)
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using "inner join", if the values are missing in the `items_x_lists` table, nothing will show.

You want to use a "left join" if you want to include everything from `lists`, even if there are no values in `items_x_lists`.

```
SELECT 
    lists.id, 
    lists.name, 
    COUNT(items_x_lists.listId) AS count, 
    SUM(items_x_lists.purchased) AS purchased
FROM lists
LEFT JOIN items_x_lists ON lists.id=items_x_lists.listId
GROUP BY lists.id;
```

Here are the different types of the JOINs in SQL:

- (INNER) JOIN: Returns records that have matching values in both
  tables
- LEFT (OUTER) JOIN: Returns all records from the left table,
  and the matched records from the right table
- RIGHT (OUTER) JOIN:
  Returns all records from the right table, and the matched records
  from the left table
- FULL (OUTER) JOIN: Returns all records when there
  is a match in either left or right table

Comment: Thanks! You are right I was supposed to do a LEFT JOIN instead. 
Here is my fixed query:
```
SELECT lists.id, name, COUNT(items_x_lists.listId) AS count, IFNULL(SUM(items_x_lists.purchased), 0) AS purchased
FROM lists
LEFT JOIN items_x_lists ON lists.id=items_x_lists.listId
GROUP BY lists.id;